# Change the font color of text inside div tag on hovering

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the color of the text and underline it, when a user hovers over a text.

I tried the following and it doesn't work. I did look for a solution all over the internet and I didn't find any that suited my particular need.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container{ width: 100px; float: left; background: #e2edf9; overflow: hidden; }
    .content {width: 10px; height:20px; cursor: pointer; color: black; }
    .content:hover{color: orange;}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="content" onclick="search(this)" >**EWR**</div>
    <div class="content" onclick="search(this)" >**NRT**</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the :hover pseudo-class is not supported by older browsers, like IE6 and below

Comment: .. but that shouldn't be an issue. Still developing for IE6 is silly.

Comment: @GolezTrol pardon me, I'm developing for IE8.

Comment: I'm pretty sure IE6 issues are irrelevant by now, as it's barely used. Your style is fine. Make sure you have html declaration (<!DOCTYPE html> ) first thing in your document. And all the rest should be valid HTML. On a snippet like that it won't work as it's not a valid HTML document.

Comment: When I see a div with an onclick handler, I always wonder why not use an `a href`.

Comment: @GolezTrol OK we now know its IE8, but as the codes in the question is valid and correct the issue could very well, silly or not, have been that the OP used IE6

Comment: @Muleskinner Very true. I wasn't trying to trivalise your comment, but merely expressing the hope that OP wasn't using IE6.

Comment: @Muleskinner I think IE8 doesn't support pseudo-class either.

Comment: `:hover` works in IE8 for me, the [quirks mode hover test page](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/hover.html), at least. Does that work for you, @javaStudent ?

Comment: @javaStudent I really think we need to see your rendered html code (ie a copy from view source) to solve this

Comment: To those who says that "developing for IE6 is silly" or that "IE6 issues are irrelevant": tell it to the 100.000.000+ Chinese IE6 users ;o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IE there must be declared a  <!DOCTYPE> for the :hover selector to work on other elements than the <a> element.

I'm not so sure about :hover support on elements other than link in <IE6.

If push comes to shove there is always your javascript whip:

```
<div class="content" onmouseover="this.style.color = 'orange'" onmouseout="this.style.color = 'black'" ></div>
```

Comment: When all else fails, I will give javascript a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

CSS:

```
.container{ width: 100px; float: left; background: #e2edf9; overflow: hidden; }
.content {width: 10px; height:20px; cursor: pointer; color: #000000; }
.content:hover{color: #FFA500; text-decoration: underline;}
```

**​Not all browsers accept words as colors try using HEX-code or rgb().**

See: http://jsfiddle.net/davcpas123/3S4xN/2/

Update:

Strange seems fine to me:

[image]

Comment: I'm using IE8. I changed the color to hex-code and it still doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with this?

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container{ width: 100px; float: left; background: #e2edf9; overflow: hidden; }
    .content {width: 10px; height:20px; cursor: pointer; color: black; }
    .content:hover{color: #FFFFFF;text-decoration:underline;}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="content" onclick="search(this)" >**EWR**</div>
    <div class="content" onclick="search(this)" >**NRT**</div>
</div>​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m4m7B/1/

Comment: I didn't know you could try out your code in the website you provided. It works fine in jsfiddle but when I run the same code on my machine, the font color doesn't change nor it gets underlined. Could it be because I'm using IE8?

Comment: Yep that's possible. Try to use HEX-Code (like #FFFFFF for white color)

Comment: It shouldn't matter. Using `orange` should work just fine in IE8.

Comment: You need to show us your whole code. Maybe you are missing a DOCTYPE or something which causes the bug.

Comment: @Chris I tried the hex-code and it doesn't work either. I added the doctype in my original question.

Comment: Maybe post all of your code to jsfiddle and add the page to you question above so we can take a look at it.

Comment: I'm using scriptlet to generate the "div" statements. Can that be a problem?

Comment: Here is the full code. I have used scriptlets. I understand it's not a good practice but I couldn't figure out an alternate way of doing it. http://jsfiddle.net/Bx3V2/

Comment: I don't really now Java/scriptlets. You better learn plain HTML/CSS first. My posted code is just fine and should work on every browser (except IE6).

Comment: @Muleskinner I know.. it's horrible. I had to display a list of string vertically in alphabetic order and the only way I could figure out of doing it was by using scriptlet. Is there another cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: @Chris I tried your code and I tested it on firefox and it works. But my user usees IE8.

Comment: @javaStudent not really sure what you are trying to do but the result window in your jsfiddle looks weird to me

Comment: @Muleskinner Chris asked me to show him my full code, that's why I put it there.

Answer (score 1):

This fiddle works for me in IE8, [see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/m4m7B/1/), except when running in quirks mode, do you have quirks mode on?

Is javascript an option, seems like the best solution for you.

Comment: I can work with javascript. But I am not sure what quirks mode is?

Comment: Quirks mode [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), you can tell IE which compatibility mode to run using developer tools.